# Xcode 6 Wont Correctly Install iOS 7 SDK

Tags: xcode

I downloaded the iOS 7 sdk in xcode 6.1.1 but found it was only the simulator and I couldnt use it as a base sdk. I checked in the xcode.app and found that the ios 7 sdk files were there under the simulator sdk directory, but not in the iPhoneOS.sdk directory. I tried to delete the xcode 7 sdk in the simulator and restart the download, but it always starts half way through. How can I fully remove the iOS 7 sdk and redownload it fully so I can use it as a base sdk?

Comment: Obviously you can't use an old sdk as base.

Comment: A week ago I installed the iOS 7 sdk and I could use it as a base sdk. But a few days ago I had to reinstall OS X so I lost it.